# Django csrf protection if form in javascript file

Tags: django, django-templates, django-csrf

Let's say I have form in javascript file:

```
function form(csrf){
    document.write('<form action="" method="post">'+csrf);
    document.write(....);
    document.write('<button>Go</button></form>');
}
```

In template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    form({% csrf_token %});
</script>
```

Is it safe to do that?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You may need to put quotes around the csrf_token, like `form("{% csrf_token %}")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tag simply generates a hidden field and that's what you would be passing to the function.

Nothing wrong with that.

Comment: So you mean everything is OK with that?

Comment: Yes, tag generates hidden field, but user can not change it. But when form is in javascript file - user can change that hidden field...

Comment: Define what you mean by "OK" :-)

Comment: One could change the hidden field value if one wanted to using Firebug in the DOM as well. That is precisely why the CSRF middleware checks the value to ensure it hasn't been tampered with.

Comment: by OK I mean that user can not do CSRF (sorry for Enflish)